# Are questions about developing a language specification on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, asking-questions

I am considering asking a question along the lines of *'How could I best describe a `void` or `never` type in a formal language specification?'*

However I thought that ***may*** be more of an English question than a technical question.

Should questions about writing a language *specification* (a document that details the features, syntax, standard library, and requirements of a programming language) be considered on-topic? What are the guidelines for asking such questions?

Comment: Related: https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/475/38

Answer (score 5):

### Yes

Writing the specification is a essential part of language design. As long as it's about best describing technical concepts.

If your questions starts being more about grammar or presentation it might fit better on another site.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, that should be the central focus of a website about programming language design. In my vocabulary, programming language design simply means to write its specification in a sensible way.